# Debian 10 Hyper V compatibility

Tags: debian, compatibility, hyper-v

Based on this [link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/virtualization/hyper-v/supported-debian-virtual-machines-on-hyper-v) the Hyper-V 2019 is compatible with Debian 10.0 up to Debian 10.3.

Is this a strict case or can I use 10.5 or even 10.7 without any problems?

Comment: It will work but it just isn't going to be supported.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

10.*x* releases are backwards-compatible with previous 10.*x* releases, and the kernel is still based on the same stable branch, so you shouldn’t have any problem running the latest 10.*x* point-release on Hyper-V 2019.